# Lagrange inversion formula in positive characterisic

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Does there exist an analog of Lagrange inversion formula  in positive characteristic? Obviously, the formula is still valid for coefficient with index not divisible by the characteristic, but for the other ones I did not manage to find one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many forms of Lagrange inversion. The ones that don't involve division by integers are valid in positive characteristic. For example:
Given a power series $R(t)$, there is a unique  power series $f=f(x)$ such that
$f(x) = x R(f(x))$, and for any  Laurent series $\phi(t)$ and $\psi(t)$   and any integer $n$ we have

$$[x^n]\phi(f)=[t^n]\bigl(1-tR'(t)/R(t)\bigr)\phi(t)R(t)^n$$
and
$$[x^n]\frac{\psi(f)}{ 1-xR'(f)}=[t^n]\psi(t)R(t)^n.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have references for these formulas?

Comment: Ira M. Gessel, Lagrange inversion, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A 144 (2016), 212-249, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2016.06.018.

Comment: I did not manage to use your formula to explicit the coefficients of the inverse of a power series (for the composition). Can you explain how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To find the compositional inverse $f(x)$ of $g(x)$, let $R(t) = t/g(t)$ and solve $f=xR(f)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Your answers are very useful.